# Speedfan won't automatically regulate

Tags: windows, automation, fan, speedfan

I used to have Speedfan regulating my fan speed automatically, but ever since I've reformatted, I can't get this to work. I've done the following:

1. In Temperatures, I have only CPU checked with CPU checked beneath it, set to a desired temperature of 60 degrees Celsius (ideally I'd like that to be lower, but I'll play with that once I get it regulating at all).
   [image]
2. In Speeds, I've set a minimum and a maximum speed, and selected Automatically Varied.
   [image]
3. On the main page, I've checked "Automatic fan speed".
   [image]

That should be it, right? As you can see from the last screenshot, the temperature is well below the 60 degrees I set it to, but the fan speed remains at 100%. If I manually adjust it, the fan does slow down accordingly, but automatic fan control just doesn't do anything. This used to work on this computer, prior to the reformat, and it seems to me like Speedfan just isn't trying to do the automatic speed control (since manually adjusting the fan works just fine).

Have I missed or improperly configured something? What might be preventing the automatic fan control from working properly?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you installed the same drivers for your mainboard?

Comment: I'll confirm, but if this were a driver issue, wouldn't I not be able to change the speed manually? I would think the issue is on Speedfan's side, because it can clearly monitor temperatures and adjust fan speeds. It looks like it's just not even trying, for some reason.